# condensed protocol for sequencing a portion of human DNA from buccal sample

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing, pcr, human-genome

Anyone have a short & sweet protocol for PCR amplifying a region of human DNA (chromosomal or mt, I don't care) extracted from a buccal sample: including validated primer sequences and preferred method of DNA isolation from a buccal swab. I'm looking for a new exercise to run in my classroom. We would be able to follow the amplification up with Sanger sequencing, done in-house.

Comment: Which possibilities do you have for the extraction? Would this be more "lab-like" or more "DIY-bio"-style?